# Hybris Mockito : Getting Exception there is no LocaleProvider for (detached) model

Tags: mocking, mockito, powermock, sap-commerce-cloud, powermockito

I am writing test cases at facade level in my Hybris Project. I am creating model instance and setting name and code. Model is having some attributes Localized, because of that I am getting `no LocaleProvider` Exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: there is no LocaleProvider for (detached) model de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl@66c677a7
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.getLocaleProvider(ItemModelContextImpl.java:481)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.getCurrentLocale(ItemModelContextImpl.java:469)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.toDataLocale(ItemModelContextImpl.java:406)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.getLocalizedValue(ItemModelContextImpl.java:323)
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.model.classification.ClassificationAttributeModel.getName(ClassificationAttributeModel.java:227)
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.model.classification.ClassificationAttributeModel.getName(ClassificationAttributeModel.java:217)
```

Here is a test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Locale.class, Config.class })
public class HCCB2BClassificationFacadeUnitTest {

@InjectMocks
private final HCCB2BClassificationFacade hccb2bClassificationFacade = new HCCB2BClassificationFacadeImpl();

@Mock
HCCB2BClassificationService hccb2bClassificationService = new HCCB2BClassificationServiceImpl();

@Mock
private SessionService sessionService;

@Mock
private HCCB2BClassificationDAO hccb2bClassificationDAO;

@Mock
private SearchRestrictionService searchRestrictionService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws SystemException {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ClassAttributeAssignmentModel classAttributeAssignmentModel = new ClassAttributeAssignmentModel();
    ClassificationAttributeModel classificationAttributeModel = new ClassificationAttributeModel();
    classificationAttributeModel.setCode("Procedure");
    classificationAttributeModel.setName("Procedure",Locale.ENGLISH); //Localized Variable
    classAttributeAssignmentModel.setClassificationAttribute(classificationAttributeModel);
    List<ClassAttributeAssignmentModel> classAttributeAssignmentModelList=new ArrayList<ClassAttributeAssignmentModel>();
    classAttributeAssignmentModelList.add(classAttributeAssignmentModel);
    Mockito.doReturn(null).when(sessionService).getAttribute("attributeDTOList");
    Mockito.when(hccb2bClassificationService.getClassAttributeAssignmentList(ClassificationAttributeLevel.LEVEL1,"FAC001")).thenReturn(classAttributeAssignmentModelList);
}

@Test
public void getClassificationAttributeList() {
    HCCB2BCategoryParameter categoryParamter = new HCCB2BCategoryParameter();         
    categoryParamter.setCategoryCode("FAC001");      
    Assert.assertNotNull(hccb2bClassificationFacade.getClassificationAttributeList(categoryParamter));
}
```

Here you can see I am creating instance of `ClassificationAttributeModel` and setting code and name of that. Here Name is Localized so i have given Locale.English as well. But whenever I am running this, I am getting No LocaleProvider Exception.

Actually in my facade, wherever calling `attributeValue.getName()`, getting the same exception.

For Example :

`dto.setName(classificationModel.getName());`

Can't we ignore this locale behavior or what is the alternative solution for that. Please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got the Solution....

I have to set LocaleProvider using `StubLocaleProvider` and then assign it to the ItemModelContext.

> import
>   de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.LocaleProvider;
>
> LocaleProvider localeProvider = new
>   StubLocaleProvider(Locale.ENGLISH);

Test Class -

```
    ClassificationAttributeModel classificationAttributeModel = new ClassificationAttributeModel();
    LocaleProvider localeProvider = new StubLocaleProvider(Locale.ENGLISH);
    ItemModelContextImpl itemModelContext = (ItemModelContextImpl) classificationAttributeModel.getItemModelContext();
    itemModelContext.setLocaleProvider(localeProvider);
    classificationAttributeModel.setCode("Procedure");
    classificationAttributeModel.setName("Procedure");
```